# Associate approval workflow using CSOM Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to attach approval workflow to my SharePoint libraries but each time I get an 
'value cannot be null',

but I don't find where I am going wrong,

below is my PowerShell code that I am trying

Is there any parameter that I am missing to give values ?

Other functions are just to check of the list exists and if not then to create it, 
also while creating the list I am unable to find the list template f0r Task (2010) in method createListByTemplate()

Thanks
Paru

```
 function TryGetList($spoCtx,$listName)
    {
        $web = $spoCtx.Web 
        $lists = $web.Lists
        $spoCtx.Load($web) 
        $spoCtx.Load($lists)   
        $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 
        $listExist = $web.Lists | where{$_.Title -eq $listName}
        if($listExist)
        {
            return $true
        }
        else
        {
            return $false
        }
    }

    function CreateListbyTemplate($spoCtx,$listName,$listTemplate,$listDescription)
    {
        try
        {
            $spoWeb=$spoCtx.Web
            $spoListCreationInformation=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation 
            $spoListCreationInformation.Title=$listName 
            $spoListCreationInformation.Description = $listDescription
            $spoCtx.Load($web.ListTemplates)
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
            #$spoListCreationInformation.TemplateType=[int][Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListTemplatetype]::GenericList 
            #$spoList=$spoWeb.Lists.Add($spoListCreationInformation) 
            $spoListCreationInformation.ListTemplate = $web.ListTemplates | where {$_.InternalName -match $listTemplate }
            $spoWeb.Lists.Add($spoListCreationInformation) 
            $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
            return $listName
            Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green 
            Write-Host "List "$listName"  created  !!" -ForegroundColor Green 
            $spoCtx.Dispose() 
        }
        catch  [Exception]
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "An Error Occured"
            $_.Exception.Message
        }

    }


    # $spoCtx has current context 
    function attachApprovalWorkflow($spoCtx)
    {
        try
        {

            $SuccessLogs=$records.LogImportSuccess + (get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss).ToString()+".csv"
            $FailureLogs=$records.LogImportFailure + (get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss).ToString()+".csv"
            Add-Content $SuccessLogs “ID, Status”;
            Add-Content $FailureLogs “ID,Message”;

            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$web = $spoCtx.Web


            try
            {
                $liststoignore = @("Workflow History", "Workflow Tasks", "Master Page Gallery", "Composed Looks", "MicroFeed", "Site Assets", "Site Pages","Documents", "appdata", "appfiles", "Converted Forms", "Form Templates", "List Template Gallery", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "TaxonomyHiddenList", "User Information List", "Web Part Gallery", "Theme Gallery")
                [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCollection] $lstcoll = $spoCtx.Web.Lists;
                $spoCtx.Load($lstcoll);
                $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                foreach($listsName in $lstcoll)
                {
                    if ($listsName.BaseTemplate -eq 101 -and  !$liststoignore.Contains($listsName.Title))
                        {

                            [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle($listsName.Title)

                             $spoCtx.load($list)
                             $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery();

                             ##################

                            $tasklist = TryGetList $spoCtx "Workflow Tasks"
                            if ($tasklist -eq $false)
                            {
                                $tasklist = CreateListbyTemplate $spoCtx "Workflow Tasks" "Tasks (2010)" "Workflow Tasks" + " list"
                            }
                            else
                            {[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$tasklist1 = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Workflow Tasks")
                             $spoCtx.load($tasklist1)
                             $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
                            }

                            $historylist = TryGetList $spoCtx "Workflow History"                      
                            if ($historylist -eq $false)
                            {
                                $historylist = CreateListbyTemplate $spoCtx "Workflow History" "Workflow History" "Workflow History" + " list"
                            }
                            else
                            {
                             [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List]$historylist1 = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Workflow History")
                             $spoCtx.load($historylist1)
                             $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()
                            }




                             ###################

                             $workflowName = $listsName.Title + " Workflow"
                             $wfApprovalWFTemplate = $web.WorkflowTemplates.GetByName("Approval - SharePoint 2010")

                             $spoCtx.Load($wfApprovalWFTemplate)
                             $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                             #Create a Workflow Association info
                             $wfassociationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Workflow.WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation;
                             $wfassociationInfo.ContentTypeAssociationTaskListName = $tasklist1
                             $wfassociationInfo.ContentTypeAssociationHistoryListName = $historylist1
                             $wfassociationInfo.Template = $wfApprovalWFTemplate
                             $wfassociationInfo.Name = $workflowName
                             $wfassociationInfo.TaskList =$web.Lists.GetByTitle("Workflow Tasks")
                             $wfassociationInfo.HistoryList = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("Workflow History")

                             #Associate to the Document Library where you want the approval WF to be added .
                             Write-Host "Create a new Workflow Associationg with the Neccesary information."
                             $wf = $list.WorkflowAssociations.Add($wfassociationInfo)

                             $wf.AutoStartChange = $false
                             $wf.AutoStartCreate = $false
                             $wf.AllowManual = $true
                             $wf.Update();

                             $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()

                             Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Workflow enabled on " $list.Title
                             Add-Content $SuccessLogs $list.Title
                         }
               }

            }
            catch  [Exception]
            {   
                Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "An Error Occured" $list.Title
                $_.Exception.Message
                Add-Content $FailureLogs $listsName +","+$_.Exception.Message
            }
    }
        catch [Exception]
        {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "An Error Occured"
            $_.Exception.Message + $list.Title
        }

    }
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: $wf = $list.WorkflowAssociations.Add($wfassociationInfo) this line,  while attaching the workflows to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code I shared works absolutely fine its just that
you need enable below feature in order to use SharePoint 2010 approval workflow.

[image: This feature needs to be enabled]